# Windows 10 does not boot, fails with BSOD 0x7E SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED in ntfs.sys

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have been using Windows 10 for about three months now on my Lenovo T450s and all of a sudden out of nowhere I cannot boot my PC anymore. I recieve the following BSOD message:

> SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (ntfs.sys)

I have looked around the internet for any solutions to this problem but I have not been able to find anything. Unless Windows 10 did once of it's infamous background updates, I have not done any updates to the computer.

I have tried booting into safe mode under a number of different conditions with no luck. All I get is this message. Windows 10 Automatic Repair was, as usual, unable to fix anything.

I do have Ubuntu dual booted with the system however because Windows locks the hard drives I cannot access the Windows partitions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not much to go on here.  NTFS.sys = NT File System = suspect faulty HDD and/or HDD controller.  If you're lucky it's just (massive) data corruption, if you're not lucky, you need a new drive, if your REALLY unlucky, you'll need a new HDD controller (new motherboard in most cases). So, test your drive(s).  PS I highly doubt the message said "As usual, unable to fix anything". ;)

Comment: You will need to install Windows 10 again.  Your current installation is corrupt beyond beyond Windows own ability to repair the damage.  A healthy HDD does not contain a corrupt operating system so your problems are likely connected to your storage device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I faced above was that I could not boot into Windows under any condition whether it would be a normal boot or a safe boot. I kept getting the BSOD error SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (ntfs.sys).

So it was very weird but I was fix the problem. I am not sure what happened by I ran tests on the SSD in question and it came up 100% clean and I preformed a chkdsk which also came back with no issues. So because Windows locked the drive, I was still able to open it with read only permissions in Ubuntu and look at the file system. In the file system I noticed a folder in the root directory label **$Windows.~WS**. Inside were some files that I could not make out, but I decided to rename the folder (instead of deleting it, in case it was actually important). I would like to note that even though the drive was in read only mode I was able to rename a folder which is interesting.

Anyway, I renamed the folder and booted back into Windows. I let Window boot and do its thing and it worked. Voila.

In my case, I also encountered a few **"Critical Errors"** from Windows 10 saying Start and Cortana were not working properly. After a few reboots everything now works perfectly.

It is strange as ususally with an ntfs.sys BSOD the disk drive is faulty but in my case it was not. Thanks to those with their suggestions above.

Comment: That particular folder is associated with the windows 10 upgrade install, IIRC it contains the full setup. Of course, I am left wondering how you renamed the folder on a read-only mount point.